# Firebird 2.5.2 on Fedora 19

Tags: firebird, fedora

I try to install Firebird 2.5.2 on Fedora 19 using the package list available on Fedora but i have get problems to start the Firebird service.

After a installation is proceeded, i try to start Firebird service but i get the follow message:

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  firebird.service
>
> Failed to issue method call: Unit firebird.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status firebird.service' for details.

OK, i try to uninstall the Firebird package and try install again using the own graphical interface available on Fedora 19. I try too use yum (with yours options) but nothing fix this problem.

I get the same error message when try start mysql service, but i fix this uninstall MariaDB and after, install mysql-server via yum command line. But, as i write above, with Firebird i don't have success.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the system log and did you run `systemctl status firebird.service` as the error suggests?

Answer (score 1):

since systemd :
systemctl start firebird-superserver.service
or
systemctl start firebird-superclassic.service
or
systemctl start firebird-classic.socket

see README.Fedora
http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/firebird.git/tree/README.Fedora

Comment: Thank you for link. Clarified any things.

Answer (score 0):

In my fedora 19 for firebird superserver I using:

systemctl enable firebird-superserver.service

systemctl start firebird-superserver.service

Comment: Thank you my friend. I applied this commands and service start perfectly. Thanks !!